# How to stop a GraphicsPath from closing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, gdi+

I'm trying to make an eraser tool that can erase points from a `GraphicsPath`. So far, my code lets the user paint on the form, and the "Erase" button is supposed to erase the first 20 points of the `GraphicsPath`. It works until two distinguishable drawings are made then the "Erase" button is pushed - as seen in the images, the two drawings connect. I suspect that the `GraphicsPath` closes itself (connecting each point).

Is there a way to prevent the `GraphicsPath` from connecting each point?

Here is my full code. I think the most relevant part is the function at the bottom.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cartographer
{
    public partial class testform : Form
    {

        private GraphicsPath _drawingPath = new GraphicsPath();
        private Point lastMouseLocation;
        private bool drawing = false;

        public testform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void testform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Paint += Testform_Paint;
            this.MouseMove += Testform_MouseMove;

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        private void Testform_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                drawing = true;
                _drawingPath.AddLine(lastMouseLocation, e.Location);
                Invalidate();
            }

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.None && drawing)
            {
                drawing = false;
                _drawingPath.StartFigure(); // problem is not due to this line


            }
            lastMouseLocation = e.Location;
        }

        private void Testform_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
            using (Pen p = new Pen(b, 51))
            {
                p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;

                e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, _drawingPath);

            }

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen))
            using (Pen p = new Pen(b, 50))
            {
                p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;

                e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, _drawingPath);
            }

        }

        private void btnErase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<PointF> ptsList = new List<PointF>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                ptsList.Add(_drawingPath.PathData.Points[i]);
            }

            _drawingPath = ErasePointsFromPath(_drawingPath, ptsList.ToArray<PointF>());
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private GraphicsPath ErasePointsFromPath(GraphicsPath path, PointF[] toRemove)
        {
            PointF[] newPoints = path.PathData.Points.Except<PointF>(toRemove).ToArray<PointF>();
            byte[] types = new byte[newPoints.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < newPoints.Length; i++)
            {
                types[i] = 1;
            }

            GraphicsPath ret = new GraphicsPath(newPoints, types);
            //ret.SetMarkers();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what happens. The two round-ish lines in the drawing are supposed to be separate and not connected by that diagonal one.

[image: thing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you erase the points from the path you are doing so by copying them to a new path, excluding the ones you want to erase.  But you are not also copying the corresponding point type information from the first path; instead you are resetting all the point types to 1, for whatever reason.  This loses the information about where each figure within the path starts.  So what happens is the new path sees one long connected figure, which explains what you are seeing.
If you want to erase the first *n* points from the path, you might try something like this instead:

```
private void btnErase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfPointsToErase = 20;

    if (_drawingPath.PointCount > numberOfPointsToErase)
    {
        _drawingPath = new GraphicsPath(
            _drawingPath.PathPoints.Skip(numberOfPointsToErase).ToArray(),
            _drawingPath.PathTypes.Skip(numberOfPointsToErase).ToArray()
        );
    }
    else
    {
        _drawingPath.Reset();
    }

    this.Invalidate();
}
```